# Differentiate ID according to another variable

Tags: r, string

I need to differentiate the column ID (with a letter) if they are different in other variable ("Art" in this case). Like this:

```
Id<-c("RoLu1976", "RoLu1976", "AlBlKyFy1989", "ThSa1996", "AlBlKyFy1989","ThSa1996")
Art<-c("Econometric Policy Evaluation", "Policy Right", "Rules", "Expectations", "Nonneutrality of money","Expectations")
Yr<-c(1976, 1976, 1989, 1996, 1989, 1996)
df<-data.frame(Id,Art,Yr)
```

In the above the Ids should be:

```
Id             Art                                Yr
RoLu1976a      Econometric Policy Evaluation     1976
RoLu1976b      Policy Right                      1976
AlBlKyFi1989a  Rules                             1989
ThSa1996       Expectations                      1996
AlBlKyFi1989b  Nonneutrality of money            1989
ThSa1996       Expectations                      1996
```

In this case, column ID are identical in some cases (for example with `RoLu1976`) but different in "Art" column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[, tmp := seq(uniqueN(Art)), by = Id]
df[, addition := ifelse(.N>1, "",letters[tmp]), by = .(Id, Art)]
df[, Id := paste0(Id, addition)]
df[, c("tmp", "addition") := NULL]
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(Id, Art) %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(Id2 = if(length(unique(Art)) > 1) paste0(Id, "_", letters[as.numeric(factor(Art))]) else as.character(Id)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(Id=Id2, everything(), -Id)
```

> ```
>               Id                           Art    Yr
> 1 AlBlKyFy1989_a        Nonneutrality of money  1989
> 2 AlBlKyFy1989_b                         Rules  1989
> 3     RoLu1976_a Econometric Policy Evaluation  1976
> 4     RoLu1976_b                  Policy Right  1976
> 5       ThSa1996                  Expectations  1996
> 6       ThSa1996                  Expectations  1996
> ```

Comment: The ID `ThSa1996` has the same value in Art column. It doesn't should have a letter.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand what you wanted. Shouldn't both rows of `ThSa1996` have the same letter, since they both have the same value of `Art`?

Comment: Cause `ThSa1996` have the same value in `Art` it should not be "marked" with a letter. It should be the same, i.e. `ThSa1996`. This is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`:

```
df%>%group_by(Id)%>%
  mutate(nb_art=length(unique(Art)))%>%
  mutate(lettre=letters[seq(nb_art)])%>%
  mutate(Id_letters=paste0(Id,ifelse(nb_art>1,lettre,"")))%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  mutate(Id=Id_letters)%>%
  select(Id,Art,Yr)
```

This can be shortened but it makes it very clear to read (I hope).

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
             Id                           Art    Yr
          <chr>                        <fctr> <dbl>
1     RoLu1976a Econometric Policy Evaluation  1976
2     RoLu1976b                  Policy Right  1976
3 AlBlKyFy1989a                         Rules  1989
4      ThSa1996                  Expectations  1996
5 AlBlKyFy1989b        Nonneutrality of money  1989
6      ThSa1996                  Expectations  1996
```

Comment: The ID `RoLu1976` and `AlBlKyFi1989` has different value in `Art` column. They  should have a different letter not the same.

Answer (score 1):

With for loops:

```
df$Id <- as.character(df$Id)

# loop through Ids
for(id in unique(df$Id)){
  sub <- unique(df[df$Id == id,])
  # check if this Id needs to be manipulated
  if(nrow(sub) > 1){
    # assign unique Ids
    for(j in 1:nrow(sub)){
      sub[j,1] <- paste0(sub[j,1],letters[j])
    }
    # replace old Ids with new Ids
    df[df$Id == id, ] <- sub
  } 
}
```